# Update vectors inside a nested map

Tags: clojure

I am currently operating on vectors contained inside a nested map:

```
(def map {:key1 {:key2 [1 2 3]}})
```

Now I am looking for the most practicable way to update a single value within that vector.
I am able to perform isolated updates by extraction of the vector:

```
(assoc (get-in map [:key1 :key2]) 2 '(3 4 5))
```

However, I am not sucessful in making updates inside the map.
´update-in´ would work if a function is applicable. However, I would still have send the complete vector through the function, instead of updating a single value.

Answer (score 3):

You can call `assoc-in` with the index in the vector:

```
(assoc-in map [:key1 :key2 2] '(3 4 5))
; => {:key1 {:key2 [1 2 (3 4 5)]}}
```

Comment: Yes, I was also trying around using an anonymous function together with `ùpdate-in`, but `assoc-in` is exactly what I was looking for!